# Python docker image doesn't find opencv when installed with apt-get

Tags: python, linux, docker, debian, apt-get

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv
```

Build this then get the following result:

```sh
$ docker run -it myimage:opencv python3 -c "import cv2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

$ docker run -it hazopticnano:opencv python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Within the container:

```sh
$ ls usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  numpy  numpy-1.16.2.egg-info  pkg_resources
```

If I run this then it will work:

```sh
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/
```

Is there a way I can make this work "out of the box", without having to run the last command?

Comment: why not pip install instead?

Comment: The python 3.7 in the image is not the system interpreter.  `apt` will install for the system interpreter only.

Comment: Because I want this to work on x86 and ARM processors.

Answer (score 0):

As @klaus-d said python is installed from source and not via the package manager. See https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.7/buster/Dockerfile.

You can probably chose to use pip (which should work fine on different architectures) or go with the debian image and also install python via apt.